# Get current user - signed to exchange server - manager email address

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, exchange-server-2010

How can I retrieve the current user manager email address?
I'm only able to get my e-mail address by calling the

> Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser

while using

> Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.Manager

returns nothing...
What i'm trying to achieve is to send an email to my manager right from excel sheet and automate it on other users computers (because they've other managers)

```
Sub Mail_workbook_Outlook_1()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    If IsEmpty(Range("A21").Value) = True Then ' check if cell is empty
      MsgBox "Cell is empty!", vbCritical, "It would be better to not left it empty..." ' if so, show user a message
    Else

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail ' outlook message details
        .To = "xyz@xyz.net"
        .Subject = "Sales report - " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
        .Body = "Here comes the full sales report from " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy") & Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName ' add current file as an attachment to the outlook message
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    MsgBox "File sent ", vbInformation, "You can now safely close the report" ' show confirmation message

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: Outlook contact with manager]

Comment: What do you use in OutlookSpy if you click IMAPISession | QueryIdentity? Does the IMailUser window have the PR_EMS_AB_MANAGER tab?

Comment: I haven't used OutlookSpy - but i see it has a large amount of options that would help in further development. So to answer your question: i don't know. Corporate stations have some restrictions and permissions, so i think that such software wouldn't be allowed to be run on my account anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get current User's Manager.

Example on [outlook-vba](/questions/tagged/outlook-vba)

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetManager()

    MsgBox CreateObject("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI") _
                    .CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.Manager

End Sub
```

**Edit**

Remember user must have manager setup.

Modify your code this way

```
    With OutMail ' outlook message details
        .To = CreateObject("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI") _
                    .CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.Manager

        .Subject = "Sales report - " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
        .Body = "Here comes the full sales report from " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName 'attachment File 
        .Display
'        .Send
    End With
```

Also See on MSDN Example

[How to: Get Availability Information for an Exchange User's Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb646996.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Unfortunately the code returns only an error: **Object variable or With block variable not set** I think that i've already tried it - or very similar snippet - couple of days ago

Comment: Clarification: it only happens when there's no manager set on current user. But that's not a problem ;) 
I owe you a beer Om3r!